# How to use setContentView(layout_id) second time in main_activity of android code?

Tags: android, multiple-views, setcontentview

My activity_main.xml has 2 buttons. I have implemented onClickListner(); for both of them .

For MainActivity, - > setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
This activity_main has the 2 buttons.

Button1 - setContentView(R.layout.layout1);
Button2 - setContentView (R.layout.layout2);

Is this the proper way to use?? Because..

The program runs fine. The problem is that when I click Button2, the layout2 loads, I want to come back to main_activity now, So I press 'Back' button.
The entire app closes..!! I am taken to homescreen of the phone.

How to get around this?? I say ViewSwitcher. I do not have a button to come back.

Any other way?? Please excuse for basic question and bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pretty much never call `setContentView()` more than once. What you're describing is standard backstack behavior. Either start a *new* `Activity` whatever layout you're transitioning to, or switch to using `Fragment`s, and add a new `Fragment` to the backstack instead of calling `setContentView()`.

Both approaches will give you native behavioral support for the back button.

Answer (score 1):

U have to override onBackPressed() function in your activity and again u have to setContentView to activity_main.xml and remove the super.onBackPressed from onBackPressed.

Something like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //validation if you are in second layout
    if(layout2){
       //do things
        showLayout1();
    }else{
       super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you... How do I write if(layout2) ?? How to see if current view is set to layout2?